# stuck on boot screen, FAILED to start some services

Tags: boot, 22.04

I clicked on the "get ownership" button for my main partition in the drives app, and now Ubuntu can't boot.

These messages show up and it's stuck there.

[image]

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Comment: It sounds like maybe you messed up permissions and ownership on the root partition (I'm not familiar with the "Drives app")? Such an operation usually breaks the OS beyond repair, and you'll likely have to reinstall.

Comment: What is that app called, Disks? Anyway is there really no way to fix it? Because I had some important files in the partition, and they won't show up if I try to enter through a live environment.

Answer (score -1):

1. you can recover your files by making Ubuntu live usb
2. using same you can also try to fix permission issue